# What does Cara Dune's arm tattoo signify?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In *The Mandalorian*, former Rebel Shock Trooper Cara Dune has a distinctive ring of bars tattooed around her bicep.

[image: Cara Dune glancing at her arm tattoo]

In Chapter 7 there is considerable reference to it; Greef Karga implies that the tattoo alone would provoke any Imperials who see it.

> **Karga:** At least cover your tattoo. No need to flaunt it.

(It's possible he is referring to the rebel alliance tattoo under her eye, but the action in the scene, and the fact it is the bars that she covers up, indicate otherwise.)

When Kuiil leaves the group he considers it important enough to remind her to do it.

> **Kuiil:** Don't forget to cover your stripes.

And in the ensuing montage the tattoo gets covered up.

Does this tattoo have an established meaning in the Star Wars canon, or is this a new element to *The Mandalorian*?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe her tattoo is to signify her status as a **rebel shock trooper**. They were also called **droppers** due to the fact that they were deployed via dropships, without backup, against ex-Imperial warlords. My main piece of evidence to support this theory is that the striped pattern of the tattoo bears a striking resemblance to the pattern on both clone shock trooper helmets and Imperial shock trooper helmets.

[image: Clone Shock Trooper]

[image: Imperial Shock Trooper]